# Preference Page and runtime plugins

Tags: eclipse, preferences

I have the following problem.  I have a Preferences Page that stores preferences using the Store mechanism.  Now, these preferences must be accessed from a plugin that does not include org.eclipse.ui, which means that the store mechanism is not available and I can only use the Runtime preference mechanism.

How can I use the Preference Page to create a runtime preference?

I have the following problem:

- When using preference pages, the class used is `Activator.getDefault().getPreferenceStore()`
- When using runtime plugins, the class is `new InstanceScope().getNode("<plugin id>")`;

How do I synchronize both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Eclipse: OSGI Preferences vs. PreferenceStore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5792565/eclipse-osgi-preferences-vs-preferencestore/5795901#5795901)

Basically, InstanceScope.INSTANCE.getNode("bundle.id") gives you the `org.eclipse.core.runtime.preferences.IEclipsePreferences` that backs your bundle's `org.eclipse.jface.preference.IPreferenceStore`.  You shouldn't have to sync them, as they're the same thing.

Have they been out of sync? You might have to do a IPersistentPreferenceStore#save() and/or a org.osgi.service.prefs.Preferences.flush() if they're not in sync by default (although I thought those methods were simply to write out to the disk cache).

Comment: However, that doesn't solve my scenario completely, does it?  Because the IPreferenceStore is used in a ui plugin, but I need to read the preference in a core plugin

Comment: yes, the point is you can use `InstanceScope.INSTANCE.getNode("bundle.id")` in your core plugin

Comment: Get it, the id I use should be unique for both plugins and that does the trick.  I assume that it should be the id of the core plugin also.  thanks! Accepted